# C++ How to export a static class member from a dll?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

//API mathAPI.h, both in Dll.cpp and Test.cpp

```
#ifdef __APIBUILD
#define __API __declspec(dllexport)
//#error __APIBUILD cannot be defined.
#else
#define __API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class math
{
 public:
   static __API double Pi;
   static __API double Sum(double x, double y);
};
```

// Dll.cpp __APIBUILD is defined

```
#include "mathAPI.h"

double math::Pi = 3.14;

double math::Sum(double x, double y)
{
  return x + y;
}
```

// Test.cpp __APIBUILD not defined

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "dll.lib")
#include "mathAPI.h"

int main()
{
  std::cout << math::Pi; //linker error
  std::cout << math::Sum(5.5, 5.5); //works fine
  return 0;
}
```

Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static double Math::Pi" (?Pi@Math@@2NA)

How do i get this to work?

Comment: There's either a bug in your code, or a bug in your post, since `Math::Pi` is different from `math::Pi`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better solution to get your Pi value is to create a static method to init and return it, like the following in your DLL.cpp:

```
#include "mathAPI.h"

// math::getPi() is declared static in header file
double math::getPi()
{
    static double const Pi = 3.14;
    return Pi;
}

// math::Sum() is declared static in header file
double math::Sum(double x, double y)
{
  return x + y;
}
```

This will prevent you of uninitialised value Pi, and will do what you want.

Please note that the best practice to initialize all static values/members is to initialize them in a function/method call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting members one by one, [export whole class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx). Also, I totally don't know how this code can work - you didn't provide definition for `sum()` (missing class scope operator) and that's what linker should complain about (instead of `math::Sum()`, you defined new, global `sum()`).

**mathAPI.h**

```
#ifdef __APIBUILD
#define __API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define __API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class __API math //Add __API to export whole class
{
 public:
   static double Pi;
   static double Sum(double x, double y);
};
```

**Dll.cpp**

```
#include "mathAPI.h"

double math::Pi = 3.14;

double math::Sum(double x, double y) //You missed 'math::' here before
{
  return x + y;
}
```

And that's it.

---

**EDIT**

You should still get an error, though. That's because you made a typo, that I haven't noticed (and you did not post the real code!). In your `Dll.cpp`, you wrote:

```
double math::Pi = 3.14;
```

Although you posted something different, I am sure, that your class is named `Math`, not `math`, because linker is trying to search for:

```
?Pi@Math@@2NA
```

So it is looking in class `Math`. This is the most probable guess. Though, I am pretty sure, that you did not post the **real** code, but hand-written snippet.

Comment: Same link error, not working. unresolved external symbol "public: static double Math::Pi" (?Pi@Math@@2NA)

Comment: @Nullptr Yes, you should still be getting this error, I haven't noticed one more error, see updated answer.

Comment: Does not work even with your edit. Did you test it at all?