# Static member used as default parameter leads to unresolved externals

Tags: c++

I have a confusing issue using a static member variable as a default parameter. Since the same language construct works in a different place, it might be related to project (DLL) inter-dependencies. So please accept my apologies if my example is too complex, but I should draw the whole picture since I do not have any idea what is wrong.

I have a base class (representing kind of an error code)

**ErrorBase.h**

```
class ErrorBase
{
public:
    typedef unsigned long ErrorCode;

    /// here go the error codes. For reasons I do not want to explain, I cannot use an enumeration here.
    static const ErrorCode ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;
    static const ErrorCode ERROR_OK;
    ///...and so on

    ErrorBase(ErrorCode theCode = ERROR_UNINITIALIZED);
};
```

...and in **ErrorBase.cpp**, I am assigning values to the codes...

```
const ErrorBase::ErrorCode ErrorBase::ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = 0xffffffff;
const ErrorBase::ErrorCode ErrorBase::ERROR_OK = 0x0;
//.. and so on...
```

ErrorBase is exported from a DLL which provides some general purpose classes to our project

Now I am deriving another error class for more specific errors which has additional attributes specific for the particular type of error. The class SpecificError is part of a different DLL which links to the general purpose DLL containing ErrorBase. I have not included the dllimport/dllexport shebang, but we are using this all over the place and it works in all cases. If you have doubts, I can edit my code example.

**SpecificError.h**

```
class SpecificError : public ErrorBase
{
    public:
       static const ErrorCode SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;
       static const ErrorCode SPECIFIC_ERROR_SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG;

       SpecificError(ErrorCode theCode = SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED);
};
```

... and in the **SpecificError.cpp** I am defining these values:

```
const SpecificError::ErrorCode SpecificError::SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = ErrorBase::ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;
```

Like ErrorBase, SpecificError is exported from the DLL handling specific functionality. Note that both error classes declare a constructor using the "UNINITIALIZED" value as a default for the error code.

Now I have a program being dependent on both DLLs, thus linking to both of them through the corresponding import libraries. This program includes ErrorBase.h and SpecificError.h. It does not seem to have any problems with ErrorCode.h, but about SpecificError.h I am receiving an

*LNK2001 unresolved external symbol SpecificError::ErrorCode SpecificError::SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED referenced in main.obj.*

(remark: main.cpp does not explicitly use SpecificError, it just includes the header file).

I was able to work-around the problem by removing the default parameter from the SpecificError constructor and declaring a default constructor which in its implementation calls the inherited constructor of ErrorBase passing SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED to it. This leads me to the assumption that the symbol SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED *is* properly declared and defined but cannot be used as a parameter default. However, this seems to apply to SpecificError only, everything seems fine in ErrorBase.

Toolset: I am using Visual C++ 2017 as a compiler.

Comment: As a sanity check: does your SpecificError DLL compile and link `SpecificError.cpp` ? Can you check with dependency walker if if actually _defines_ the `SpecificError::SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED` symbol?

Comment: Also, are you aware that C++17 allows [defining constants as `inline static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) without a corresponding out-of-class definition somewhere?

Comment: Why not just make it an enum?

Comment: You have currently not initialized ```const SpecificError::ErrorCode SpecificError::SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;```

Comment: @Botje: "inline": I would love to do so but there is a requirement to have our libraries backward compatible with older C++ versions. "export": Yes, the dependency walker lists all errorcode symbols.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Because I want to extend the list of error codes in derived classes as shown in the example.

Comment: @boyanhristov96: I did. But in the sample I did not assign a value to it. However, I do this in the code here and I have edited my sample accordingly.

Comment: This is probably not that good an idea. If your derived classes are developed independently from each other, the codes they define are likely to conflict. If they are all developed in a centralised manner, you can also define the codes in a centralised manner, and that's an enum.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: They are _not_ defined in a centralized manner. The list of codes shall be extended in separate libaries as I showed in my example. We were aware of the drawbacks when we designed the error handling mechanisms for our library. We have a (phyton) script checking for conflicts in our build process.

Comment: By the same token, you can have a python script that generates an enum.

Comment: Anyway, an in-class definition of `static const ErrorCode ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = 0xffffffff;` is C++98 compatible.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Thanks a lot! This works. It is not my preferred solution, but it solves my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: About enumeration: True, but we have a basic error class in a basic library defining _some_ generic codes. We derive specific classes in other libraries which are project specific. So this would lead to an accumulation of all possible error codes (regardless whether it is used in the project or not) in the basic library. This is what we want to avoid. Derived error classes shall bring in their own specific codes without the necessity to change the general purpose error class.

Comment: I think this is mistake while coding,

Comment: Unrelated: I think `typedef unsigned long ErrorCode;` and `const ErrorBase::ErrorCode ErrorBase::ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = 0xffffffff;` is a mistake that might be or become a problem. `unsigned long` is not specified to be 32 bits. It's _at least_ 32 bits. Use `std::uint32_t` instead if you want exactly 32 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recreated the linked error. Make the following changes to your files and it should work just fine based on the code snippets that you showed above:
SpecificError.cpp

```
// I sent theCode to the Base class
SpecificError::SpecificError(ErrorCode theCode) : ErrorBase(theCode)
{
// ...
}
```

In ErrorBase.cpp I just added the constructor but you probably already have this:

```
ErrorBase::ErrorBase(ErrorCode theCode) 
{ 
// ...
}
```

After I did this, I had to also move the initializations of the static consts to the .h from the .cpp files. Then I tested the code by doing:

```
    SpecificError e; // theCode ends up being 0xffffffff
    SpecificError e1(20); // theCode ends up being 20
```

I hope that this helps you.

Here is what my ErrorBase.cpp looks like:

```
#pragma once
#include"ErrorBase.h"
#include<iostream>

ErrorBase::ErrorBase(ErrorCode theCode) {
    std::cout << theCode << std::endl;
}
```

ErrorBase.h:

```
#pragma once
class ErrorBase
{
public:
    typedef unsigned long ErrorCode;

    static const ErrorCode ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = 0xffffffff;
    static const ErrorCode ERROR_OK = 0x0;

    ErrorBase(const ErrorCode = ERROR_UNINITIALIZED);
};
```

SpecificError.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include"SpecificError.h" 

SpecificError::SpecificError(ErrorCode theCode) : ErrorBase(theCode)
{

}
```

SpecificError.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "ErrorBase.h"
class SpecificError : public ErrorBase
{
public:
    static const ErrorCode SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = ErrorBase::ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;
    static const ErrorCode SPECIFIC_ERROR_SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG = -42;

    SpecificError(ErrorCode theCode = SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @boyanhristov96, but this is exactly the work-around I mentioned in my question. It works but I would like to have a default for the parameter "theCode".

Comment: Yes, you have the default in your .h file. If you have it twice it will be an error.

Comment: No, I have a _declaration_ in my .h file and a _definition_ in my c++ file

Comment: The default for the parameter the code is working correctly with your above code and the modifications to the constructor in my answer. I tested it.
SpecificError e; // theCode = 0xffffffff and SpecificError e1(20); // theCode = 20

Comment: How is this meant to be? _Replace_ the current constructor with yours (remove default for parameter theCode) -> then your code "SpecificError e" would raise a compiler error... _Add_ your constructor -> then we would have an ambiguity because we would have 2 construcutors both accepting to be called without a parameter.

Comment: I will post my full code in the answer above. I hope that it solves your problem.

Comment: I just posted it. I hope that it helps you. The constructor that has the default parameter is sufficient to handle both cases. If you don't pass anything theCode is the uninitialized value, otherwise it will be whatever value is passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you. This is basically the solution that  n. 'pronouns' m suggested in his comment - inline initialization in the header, and yes, it works (like I had mentioned in my comment back). In fact, my question "why does the linker throw errrors if I put the definition in the cpp file" is still unanswered. But I am going to leave for x-mas vacation, and since this is currently the best _answer_, I mark it as "the solution" to reward the reputation from my bounty.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry that I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it is working, the class name was missing in ErrorBase.cpp

```
const ErrorBase::ErrorCode ErrorBase::ERROR_UNINITIALIZED = 0xffffffff;
const ErrorBase::ErrorCode ErrorBase::ERROR_OK = 0x0;
```

If still not working then let me know.

Comment: Thank you. Of course you are right, but unfortunately it was my mistake made when transforming my real code into the simplified sample in my question. I edited my sample code accordingly. With the Scope of the constants specified, I do receive the linker error,.

Comment: Now, I am not able to reproduce on VS2017 or VS2019 with the provided information.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to DLL linking. Our Unittest directly includes the object files and is fine based on the same code. Only projects linking to the DLL show the issue. Did you consider this?

Answer (score 1):

You doing it wrong. The linker error means that it doesn't know where to get your constant value. You should use dynamic linkage with a first DLL. Let me show

Example of C++ class export:
[C++ How to export a static class member from a dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772450/c-how-to-export-a-static-class-member-from-a-dll)

And your code should be changed:

**ErrorBase.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_DLL
#define MAIN_DLL 1 // or you can add MAIN_DLL definition to the your first project Macroses
#endif

#if MAIN_DLL
#define ERROR_API  __declspec(dllexport) // export things to other modules
#else
#define ERROR_API __declspec(dllimport) // import things from the external DLL
#endif

class ERROR_API ErrorBase
{
public:
    typedef unsigned long ErrorCode;

    /// here go the error codes. For reasons I do not want to explain, I cannot use an enumeration here.
    static const ErrorCode ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;
    static const ErrorCode ERROR_OK;
    ///...and so on

    ErrorBase(ErrorCode theCode = ERROR_UNINITIALIZED);
};
```

**SpecificError.h**

```
#pragma once

#define MAIN_DLL 0
#include "../Dll_stack_ovfl1/ErrorBase.h" // change it to your path

class SpecificError : public ErrorBase
{
public:
    static const ErrorCode SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED;
    static const ErrorCode SPECIFIC_ERROR_SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG;

    SpecificError(ErrorCode theCode = SPECIFIC_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED);
};
```

And the final step, configure the second DLL project to link it with exports of the first one:

Configuration Properties/Linker/Input/Additional dependencies

Add something like "$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\ErrorBase.lib"

Once again its just example, I don't know the real path of "lib" file and your project name for ErrorBase DLL - change it to your specific.

Comment: Thanks, but as I had mentioned, I did not include the "DLL shebang" in my code for the sake of clarity. I did it the way you suggested but I still receive unresolved externals.

Comment: You should include everything, because your question is sounds like "I have one thing that doesn't work, but let me show another thing as example". I give you example that I checked with Visual Studio 2017 and even checked by running the whole application with DLLs. But if you want us to guess what's wrong, I guess the project settings improperly configured. Create new project from scratch and try my example.